# How to get rid of link borders when working with linked images?

Tags: html, css, border

This image describes it all:

[image]

As you can see, there is a border under each image, but not to the left or right.

Also you can see, I marked the link-tag in the inspector and it shows a frame from approximately the middle of the image till under the picture including the unwanted border.

I already removed the text-decoration from the link, but this didn't changed a thing.

As most didn't get the root of the problem, here a larger version of the screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/f/10/screenshotfgi.png/
Follow the link and click again on the picture you get.

Look at the blue box in the lower right. It is marked by Chrome as I selected the hyperlink-tag in the inspector. Here you can see, the hyperlink causes the border/space. How to get rid of this space by changing the hyperlink-tag's style?

Comment: have you tried adding style="border:0;" on img tag?

Comment: yup... look at the additional information from some seconds ago... you can see that it is the hyperlink, not the image

Comment: Don't believe what you see - read the code. You won't believe what all can cause that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had similar problem.

set `line-height: 0` for anchors or td's.

```
#your_id table a, #your_id table td {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

or manually set `height` of a or td.

```
#your_id table a, #your_id table td {
    height: 30px;
}
#your_id table a {
    display: block;
}
```

both ways work for me.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a border, that is a space.

Images, by default, site on the same line as letters like a, b, c and d. There is space below that line for the descenders you find on letters like g, j, and y.

Set the CSS vertical-align property to move the image on that line.

Answer (score 1):

Remove an image's border when it is linked without resorting to border="0":

```
a img {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0 none;
    }
```

Doesn't seem to be your issue though.

EDIT: Check the cellpadding/cellspacing of your table.  There's some kind of padding or margin being applied to your cells.

Comment: He does not have a border on the img tag. You can see that there is no border on the left or the right of the image. Also it would be blue if there was.

Comment: easwee is right, in addition, you can see in the picture, it comes from the hyperlink... the blue box in the lower right is the hyperlink and this sorrounds the area including the white border on the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using a table that might be due to the cellspacing property.

Set:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

on your table. The border that appears when img is in a link is usually blue color.

EDIT: 
Another thing that could mess up could be vertical-align. I think the default is set to baseline - try setting your vertical align to `vertical-align:top` on both td and img inside a

Comment: is already, even though the border exists, as you can see in the picture, it comes from the hyperlink

Comment: @Joern Akkermann Can you post a link to the actual code? Also your table does have border-spacing:2px (you can see that in the code inspector on the right) so there is css equivalent to cellspacing.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without a piece of sample code...

I'd say start with resetting all properties that could've caused this:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
td, td a {
    line-height: 0;
    white-space: normal
}
td, a, td a img {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Does that help?